# Reloading a pop up window in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a pop up window in ASP.NET

In this pop Up window I have two div.

1. In div one a child page is being loaded.
2. In div two a grid-view is being loaded from the same page.

In div One I have the save button, clicking which I need to update the gridview in the div two from parent page code for reference:

For div one:

```
<div>
   <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="someevent" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
</div>
```

For div Two:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="transactionFieldMapping" tabindex="-1"
                role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 68%; height: 75%;">
                    <div class="modal-content"
                        style="width: 60%; height: 95%;">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="">Data Dependency Mapping AT TestCase level</asp:Label></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" style="width: 98%; height: 90%;">
                            <table width="100%" border="0">                               
                            </table>
                            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="IframetransactionFieldMapping" frameborder="0" runat="server">
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Div ONE code will be loaded in the I-Frame available in the Div TWO

Now on click of save in DIV ONE i need to update the grid-view in div 2 on the same pop up.

***Simply i want just a post-back from the child page which is being loaded in the I-frame inside the model but keeping the modal open.***

Comment: actually your question is little bit unclear to me. what you want just a `postback` from your modal but keeping the modal open?

Comment: yup you got it right.
I need to update the model keeping it open.
But the button is getting loaded from a different page and grid-view is being added in model itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Control Toolkit is perfect for what you're after.

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit

In terms of what you're after is the [ModalPopupExtender](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASP/) tool.

Take your time in understanding how they work and how to use them. There are tonnes of videos and forum posts on these tools and it's the way I've learnt how to use them.

Here's a tip for what you're after in particular - **asp:UpdatePanel**

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Jquery Method.

When you Click div1 Save button a jquery method will call whose responsibility is to take values of div1 to controller or server.
and returns a value which you need to show in div2.
when your methods returns successfully you can update the div2 with data which you getting from controller.

In such a way you can update div2 without closing the modal.